# Find nearest from given list for entire column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `list` of some numbers. I want to find closest value from list for entire column:

```
mylist=[11,44,23,66,100]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Data':[11,22,33,43,52,63]})
df>>
    Data
0   11
1   22
2   33
3   43
4   52
5   63
```

My desired output:

```
    Data    Nearest
0   11      11
1   22      23
2   33      23
3   43      44
4   52      66
5   63      66
```

I have tried by using `min` function with `iteraration` but its slow

Comment: For the value `52`, `44` is the closest value?

Comment: yes its 44.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns=['Nearest']).sort_values(by='Nearest')#Create DataFrame from list

pd.merge_asof(df, df1,left_on="Data", right_on="Nearest",direction="forward")#Merge asof

    Data  Nearest
0    11       11
1    22       23
2    33       44
3    43       44
4    52       66
5    63       66
```

Or

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df, df1,left_on="Data", right_on="Nearest",direction="nearest"))



    Data  Nearest
0    11       11
1    22       23
2    33       23
3    43       44
4    52       44
5    63       66
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and pass a `lambda` function which takes gives the index with minimum absolute difference, then just take the item from the list for that index.

```py
df['Nearest'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: mylist[(min([(idx,abs(x - v)) for idx, v in enumerate(mylist)], key= lambda x: x[1]))[0]])


   Data  Nearest
0    11       11
1    22       23
2    33       23
3    43       44
4    52       44
5    63       66
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work,

```
def nearest(a, x):
    n = [abs(i-x) for i in a]
    idx = n.index(min(n))
    return a[idx]

def nearest_alternative(a, v):
    idx = (np.abs(a-v)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

df['nearest'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: nearest(mylist, x))
```

alternative:

O/P:

```
   Data  nearest
0    11       11
1    22       23
2    33       23
3    43       44
4    52       44
5    63       66
```

Explanation:

- `nearest` function will receive mylist and each element of Data.
- Compute difference between x and mylist
- Return element which has minimum value